# How to display multiple menu based on conditions

Tags: ionic2

I am Beginner to ionic 2

Below are my HTML code which am using to enable side menu using ionic framework

```
<ion-content>
<ion-list  *ngIf="!isUserLoggedIn()">
      <button menuClose ion-item  *ngFor="let p of loginPages"  (click)="openPage(p)">
        {{p.title}}
      </button>
    </ion-list>
    <ion-list  *ngIf="isUserLoggedIn()">
      <button menuClose ion-item  *ngFor="let p of logoutpages"  (click)="openPage(p)">
        {{p.title}}
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
```

This is my app component

```
  currentuser;
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
  auth:any;
  rootPage: any = LoginPage;
  loginPages:PageInterface[]=[
      { title: 'Login', component: LoginPage  }
  ];

  logoutpages :PageInterface[] = [

      { title: 'My Complaints', component: MycomplaintsPage },
      { title:'My Neighbours',component:NeighboursPage},
      { title:'Notifications',component:NotificationsPage},
      { title:'Directory',component:TabsPage},
      { title:'chat',component:ChatlistPage},
      { title:'Events',component:EventPage},      
      { title:'settings',component:SettingsPage},
      { title: 'LogOut',component:LoginPage,logsOut:true }

    ];
isUserLoggedIn(): boolean {
    let user = this.authservice.getcurrentuser();
 return user !== null;

  }
```

already i display logoutpages based on isUserLoggedIn.
I need display another menu based on userrole with conditions

Kindly advice me,
Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can give ID to the menu and enable or disable the menu based on your condition.
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/tree/master/demos/src/menu

`menu.enable(true/false, #menu);`

Comment: Thanks For ur Reply.I called new funtion in after isUserLoggedIn().cannot console the value.this is my function check()
  {
    var auth=localStorage.getItem('email');
    if(auth !=null)
    {
      this.authservice.checkRole();
    }
  }

Comment: try window.localStorage.getItem('email') and even check for undefined along with null(auth != 'undefined').

Comment: i called this function constructor.Check following conditions ion-list  *ngIf="currentuser === '6'">
      <button menuClose ion-item  *ngFor="let p of loginPages"  (click)="openPage(p)">
        {{p.title}}
      </button>
    </ion-list> cannot disply menu but my role id is also "6"

Comment: when run this project auth set to be null.after login cannot  display menu.again this app refresh without logout.localstorage set to be auth value again display the menu